# Is there a function with PDO mixing integer and string together?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Does anyone knows is there a function/statement that mix integer and string together at the end of bindParam PDO::PARAM_ ..here is an example:

```
$stmt = $dbc->prepare("INSERT INTO names (user_name, user_pass) VALUES (?, ?))"; 
$stmt->bindParam(1, $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $pass, PDO:: ????);
```

As you see its for the password. And as you know some people use a mixed password with numbers and alphabetics.

Comment: That's a simple string.

Comment: You can go with `PARAM_STR` as well on both string and integer combination!!

Comment: i didn't know that, thanks alot  now I am less worried because I was unsure what to use in the password section and I kept searching google and I couldn't find the answer! thank you all!

Comment: Example input please for $name and $pass.